# Finding relation between a tilt angle and electric current through conductive frame

Tags: electromagnetism

In a conductive wire with mass density $ \lambda $ we have current I. On the wire we have a conductive frame that can rotate around the wire (the wire is the rotation axis). In addition, There's magnetic field B in the wire plane that create 90 degrees angle with the wire (as described in the photo). I need to find relation between the tilt angle of the frame, and the current $ I $ of the wire. The measurments of the frame given in the photo.
Im not sure how to start. I realize that in any given angle $ \theta $ the magnetic force on the frame will be just the magnetic force on the part with the length $ L/2 $. because the forces on the other parts are with opposite directions.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: (a) "I need to find relation between the tilt angle of the frame, and the current  of the wire." Aren't the angle and the current independent of each other? (b) Is $\theta$ in the plane of the wire/loop?

Comment: @PhilipWood $\theta$ is the angle between the frame and the wire (the frame can rotate around the wire). The magentic field is constant, so for different angles we'll have different Lorentz force on the frame, I guess somehow it will affect the current as the current isnt constant. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: I'm guessing that the wires are insulated from the "conductive frame". Is the weight of the frame of concern?

Comment: @R.W.Bird Yes it is. I guess it should be a torque equation=0 because the system will reach equilibrium state

Answer (score 0):

Since the resistance of the circuit is not given, I will assume that we are given a constant current, I, and are looking for the magnetic force on the moving segment of wire. The force will be perpendicular to B with a magnitude of I(L/2)B that is independent of the angle.

Comment: What I wrote here was the exact form of how the question was published in our course page. Ot is indeed very unclear, but I think what they ment was to find the angle theta in equilibrium that caused from lorentz force (the force will act on the $l/2$ length wire and will reach equilinrium. This angle $theta$ will depend on the current, and it will also depend on the magnetic field ofcourse.

Comment: In the absence of other forces (except a little friction) the system will stabilize with the segments of length L at 90 degrees to the magnetic field.  If you want to add a gravitational field  in the opposite direction of the B field, then you will need a equation showing the torques (relative to the long wire) from the magnetic force and and from the weights of the three segments.